# Patator error because of freerdp

Tags: freerdp

I am pentesting my host with ncrack trying to get my password
When starting ncrack i have such error

Need some help please

```
10:54:12 patator    INFO - 132   587    1.390 | 217.20.172.45:user:admin           |   177 | 
[10:54:11:604] [29975:29977] [INFO][com.freerd                                                                    p.client.x11] - Authentication only. Don't connect to X.
[10:54:12:914] [29975:29977] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_set_last_error E                                                                    RRCONNECT_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED [0x00020009]
[10:54:12:914] [29975:29977] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.transport] - BIO_read returned an error                                                                    : error:14094419:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert access denied
[10:54:12:914] [29975:29977] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - Authentic                                                                    ation only, exit status 1
[10:54:12:914] [29975:29977] [ERROR][com.freerdp.client.x11] - Authentication only, exit status 1
```